# Is there a synchronous alternative of setState() in Reactjs functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I know how to do this in class components but when i use same code in functional component i get an error. This is what i want -

```
this.setState({cnt:this.state.cnt+1})
alert(this.state.cnt);
```

now i want the alert to show count as 1 . 
How we do it in class component -

`this.setState({cnt:this.state.cnt+1}, () => alert(this.state.cnt));`

But when i do same in functional component like this

```
const[count, setCount] = useState(0);
setCount(count+1, () => alert(count));
```

I get an error - "expected no of arguments - 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State updater with react-hooks doesn't provide a callback. You need to use useEffect to achieve the same behavior. Also since you would want the useEffect to run only on update you can disable its initial execution with the help of a useRef

```
setCount(prev => prev+1);
...
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
   if(!initialRender.current) {
     alert(count);
   } else {
     initialRender.current = false;
   }
}, [count]);
```

In some cases you may not want the useEffect to trigger whenever count is updated but only when count is updated from a special function. In such cases you can make use of `useRef`

```
const runEffect = useRef(false);
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
   if(!initialRender.current) {
     // This will only be executed when you toggle ref

     alert(count);
   } else {
     initialRender.current = false;
   }
}, [runEffect.current]);
// adding ref as a dependency is fine here since we know that a re-render will be triggered by setCount


someFunction = () => {
   setCount(prev => prev + 1);
   runEffect.current = !runEffect.current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am already using the useEffect(). In useEffect() I am sending the get request to get the latest count from database once its updated. So i think the Database is taking some time to update. Does that happen?

Comment: The read from database would be asynchronous and would not gurantee result before execution of useEffect post setCount. Probably write in DB would give you a promise which you can then use

Comment: You can use more than one instance of useEffect() in your component. So, try creating another one with 'count' as a dependency.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri That was spot on. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The pattern here is to also use a `useEffect` hook with a dependency array of the state value you want to alert on. The effect hook runs once per render when state updates, and the dependency array helps filter when the effect actually triggers, in this case when count updates.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  alert('count updated!);
}, [count]);
```